# Is there any way to write italic or bold in vim

Tags: vim, gvim

Is there any way to write italic and/or bold in Vim?

Comment: I believe vim is pure text (no formating)

Comment: @ravery there is no such thing as pure text ;)

Comment: @Zanna What do you mean?

Comment: @Zanna - anything that is ASCII code only (no font, tabs, etc) is pure text. though, some editors display with a certain font or charactor highlights it is not part of the file.

Comment: @ravery Tabs are there BTW)) it is ASCII.

Comment: @Pilot - tabs aren't converted to spaces?? it been awhile since I looked at an ASCII table :)

Comment: Obviously not converted.

Comment: @Pilot6 https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: In Linux "pure text" means unicode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply these effects to some text after writing it using `:match` and `cterm=<effect>`. You make a label with `:highlight` then reference the label... I will demonstrate.

This is in terminal Vim, not gVim.

```
:highlight foo cterm=bold
:match foo /regex matching text to make bold/
```

[image]

[image]

The effect is not very strong... *shrug*

For italic, use `cterm=italic`

```
:highlight bar cterm=italic
:match bar /regex matching text I want italic/
```

[image]